# Addresses of values in an array aren't static C#

Tags: c#, arrays, pointers

So, I am currently making a little code with some pointers. I am trying to get every values of an array, and their respective address. However, the initial array is empty, and the user has to enter numbers as an input, which ends up being added to the array itself. Then, I want to get the address of each value that the user added, one by one. Everything works fine, except one thing; I want every value to have a static address. However, I noticed that at every inputs, every values had a different address than the one they had before. I tried to put the array as a global static variable, but it still doesn't work. Any help?

Thanks for everyone who takes their time to answer! <3

Full code:

```cs
using System;

public class ClearIt
{
   public int k = 8;
}

public static class Arr
{
    public static int StaticAddress;
    public static int[] x = { };
}

public class Class
{
    public static unsafe void Main()
    {
        ClearIt clearIt = new ClearIt();

        int k2 = clearIt.k;

        for (int j = 0; j < 1;)
        {
           string Read = Console.ReadLine();

         int ReadToInt;

            bool isTrue;

            isTrue = int.TryParse(Read, out ReadToInt);
            if (!isTrue)
            {
                return;
            }
           int StaticAdd = Arr.StaticAddress = ReadToInt;
            if (k2 > 0)
            {
                var xList = Arr.x.ToList();
                xList.Add(StaticAdd);
                Arr.x = xList.ToArray();
                Array.Sort(Arr.x);
                k2--;
            }
            
            else if(k2 == 0)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;

                var xList2 = Arr.x.ToList();
                    xList2.Clear();
                Arr.x = xList2.ToArray();
                Console.WriteLine("Array cleared.");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                k2 = 8;
            }

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine("\nValues\tAddresses");

            for (int i = 0; i < Arr.x.Length; i++)
            {
                fixed (int* y = &Arr.x[i])
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                    Console.WriteLine("\n" + *y + $"\t{(long)y:X}\n");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `public static int[] x = { };` is not valid syntax. Did you mean `public static int[] x = new int[0];` ?

Comment: I used this to make an empty array, and it seems to work just fine, I have no error message

Comment: None of the code above uses pointers. A pointer would be defined as `int* ptr` and compiled under an `unsafe` block.

Comment: The last block of code does use a pointer, and the method Main is a static unsafe void method

Comment: Put the loop inside the `fixed(int* ptr = &Arr.x[0])` block and then pull the values with `ptr[i]` which advances the pointer the appropriate amount of bytes for the type.

Comment: A lot of details are missing here. What user inputs? What are you expecting and what are you getting, and what is your question? If you want to store a memory address use `IntPtr` and I think you are trying to implement fixed-size buffers which are defined only under `struct` types. This is not even close to minimum verifiable code needed to reproduce the issue. Please [edit] the question to add more details.

Comment: Here, I edited it and added the full code instead. Hope this can be enough to understand my problem! And, my question is: How can I make it so the address of each values from the Array (Arr.x) NEVER changes, except when I restart the code.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Why do you need the memory address of the array elements?

Comment: `ClearIt` adds nothing to the question at hand, the `for` loop is infinite and could probably be replaced by a `while` statement for clarity, the appending to the array each time is confusing, instead of building a `List<int>` and then in the end copy the data into the "static" array. In the end we are left questioning why? what is the goal here? Why call `xList2 = Arr.x.ToList();` and immediately after `xList2.Clear();`? None of it makes any sense to me.

Comment: You can not trust the memory location of anything in C# unless it's specifically allocated for the purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that everytime you assign to `Arr.x` you are creating a new array and a new part of memory is used.

The statement below for example causes `Arr.x` address to change

```
Arr.x = xList2.ToArray();
```

If you do not want to change the address of `Arr.x`, then only assign it once to the maximum length, and keep track of the item count actually stored.

My best guess is that you are trying to do something like this

[image: fig1]

where the addresses in memory do not change when items are added or the
array is cleared. After the 8th number is added, the list clears

[image: fig3]

and more numbers can be added

[image: fig2]

As you can see the address value does not change.

I am using fixed buffer arrays to store the values, instead of the regular array. Here is the code that generates the output above

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var arr = new FixedArray();

        do
        {
            Console.Clear();

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.WriteLine($"{"offset"}\t{"address"}\t{"value"}");
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                Console.Write($"{i}");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.Write($"\t{arr.GetItemAddress(i)}");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.WriteLine($"\t{arr[i]:X}");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
            }
            if (arr.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Array Cleared.");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Enter Value:");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (int.TryParse(input, out int value))
            {
                if (arr.Add(value))
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    arr.Clear();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
            
        } while (true);
    }
}
```

and `FixedArray` is the object that actually stores the data

```
public unsafe struct FixedArray
{
    public const int Size = 8;
    fixed int data[Size];

    public FixedArray(params int[] array) : this()
    {
        Count = Math.Min(Size, array.Length);
        fixed (int* ptr = data)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
            {
                ptr[i] = array[i];
            }
        }
    }

    public IntPtr GetItemAddress(int offset = 0)
    {
        fixed (int* ptr = &data[offset])
        {
            return (IntPtr)ptr;
        }
    }
    public int this[int offset]
    {
        get
        {
            if (offset >= 0 && offset < Count)
            {
                return data[offset];
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
    public int Count { get; private set; }
    public void Clear() { Count = 0; }
    public bool Add(int x)
    {
        if (Count < Size)
        {
            data[Count] = x;
            Count++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public int[] ToArray()
    {
        int[] array = new int[Count];
        fixed (int* ptr = data)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
            {
                array[i] = ptr[i];
            }
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

---

You don't have to use a fixed buffer array. You can just use a standard array, but with the `readonly` keyword so it only gets assigned once. Use the class below as a replacement to `FixedArray` above.

```
public class StdArray
{
    public const int Size = 8;
    public int Count { get; private set; }
    readonly int[] data;

    public StdArray(params int[] array)
    {
        data = new int[Size];
        Count = Math.Min(Size, array.Length);
        Array.Copy(array, data, Count);
    }
    public unsafe IntPtr GetItemAddress(int offset = 0)
    {
        fixed (int* ptr = &data[offset])
        {
            return (IntPtr)ptr;
        }
    }
    public int this[int offset]
    {
        get
        {
            if (offset >= 0 && offset < Count)
            {
                return data[offset];
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
    public void Clear() { Count = 0; }
    public bool Add(int x)
    {
        if (Count < Size)
        {
            data[Count] = x;
            Count++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public int[] ToArray()
    {
        int[] array = new int[Count];
        Array.Copy(data, array, Count);
        return array;
    }
}
```

Comment: See the update above with sample code on what I might think you are asking for in terms of functionality.

Comment: Amazing. This is pure genius. Sorry if my request wasn't exactly clear, I am very new to all those pointers stuff, and still is learning them. Your code above even helped me getting a bit more knowledge about those things. Thank you, truly! :D

Comment: @Plattyz - add additional update. I added the class `StdArray` to replace `FixedArray` as it provides the same functionality but uses a standard array instead of a fixed buffer. This is closer to your original code I think.